# How do I show that a singular word is louder than any other in a sentence when writing it?

Tags: typography, emphasis

I know that when a word is capitalized it expresses yelling.

What about text showing someone is talking and emphasizing a particular word, but he clearly isn't yelling the word out?

How is a "non-yelling" emphasis shown in text?

Comment: Maybe you try *italics* or **bolding**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(linguistics)#Prosodic_stress

> *I* didn't take the test yesterday. (Somebody else did.)
>
> I *didn't* take the test yesterday. (I did not take it.)
>
> I didn't *take* the test yesterday. (I did something else with it.)
>
> I didn't take *the* test yesterday. (I took a different one.)
>
> I didn't take the *test* yesterday. (I took something else.)
>
> I didn't take the test *yesterday*. (I took it some other day.)
>
> As in the examples above, stress is normally transcribed as italics in printed text or underlining in handwriting.

Comment: And as caps in media which don't support italics or underlining.

Comment: @StoneyB I would prefer * asterisks * if there is no support for italics or underlining. Also, how would * you * put emphasis on the first word of the sentence, 'I'?

Comment: Me, I like asterisks, too.